# How to find proper header file from documentation

Tags: code-documentation, c++builder-2010

Really basic question here -

How am I supposed to determine the proper header file from Embarcadero's (or other) documentation when I already know what component I want to use?

For example, I am writing some ADO code, so I am getting errors like "unknown type name 'TADOConnection'".  I could have just asked that question, but I want to know where I am supposed to find that in the documentation so I don't have to ask the same question for some other component next time, I can look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation TELLS you which header to use.

For instance, the [`TADOConnection` documentation in 10.3 Rio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection) says:

[image]

Whereas the [`TADOConnection` documentation in 2010](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ADODB.TADOConnection) says:

[image]